# How to mock App Exchange package's API response?

Tags: apex, unit-test, mock, fflib

I am using an app exchange package in my code, they have exposed a few global methods that I can use to get my job done. It all works beautifully. The issue comes with testing.

I want to test positive, negative test scenarios to see my code handle's App Exchange packages' response elegantly.

That app exchange package does callout and parses, I don't know the actual HTTP Response JSON structure or mock so I cannot use `Test.setMock`.

The next thing I investigated is to use [Stub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm). Which sounded perfect but when I tried this mock I got an exception.

> System.TypeException: Test.createStub() can only be called with
>   classes in the current namespace

AppExchange Package Code:

```
AppExchangePackage.Api api = new AppExchangePackage.Api();
AppExchangePackage.ApiData.ScreenResponse response = api.screen(entityId); //Can be PersonAccount , Lead, Contact Id
```

Is there an elegant way to mock `api.screen` method so that I get my desired `ScreenResponse` in test context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot mock app-exchange package method, but I can mock my method, which calls the package. This will stop the code entering package and get me to do what I want.

```
public class APIProcessingService
{

    public ppExchangePackage.ApiData.ScreenResponse submit(Id entityId){
        AppExchangePackage.Api api = new AppExchangePackage.Api();
        AppExchangePackage.ApiData.ScreenResponse response = api.screen(entityId); //Can be PersonAccount , Lead, Contact Id
        return response;
    }

}
```

Test:

```
@isTest
public class APIProcessingServiceTest{


    public class APIProcessingMockProvider implements System.StubProvider {

        public Object handleMethodCall(Object stubbedObject, String stubbedMethodName,
                Type returnType, List<Type> listOfParamTypes, List<String> listOfParamNames,
                List<Object> listOfArgs) {


            if(stubbedMethodName =='submit'){
                return new AppExchangePackage.ApiData.ScreenResponse(); //My Mock for success or failure response

            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    @isTest
    public static void testMethodPositive(){

        Account acc =  [SELECT  Id FROM  Account LIMIT  1];

        APIProcessingService rs = (APIProcessingService) Test.createStub(APIProcessingService.class , new APIProcessingMockProvider());
        Object resp =rs.submit(acc.Id);
        System.debug(resp);



    }
}
```

The only downside is, as the code is not entering the package, the package level validations won't work.

Comment: +1 (so rare to see a use of `System.StubProvider`)

Comment: @cropredy Yeah, `System.StubProvider` is quite powerful tbh, It gives me real feeling that I am mocking. ApexMocks , fflib have good mocking, but a steep learning curve

Comment: you should reach out to me on chat some time -- I can help with apexmocks